# Objective-C Strings

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I am reviewing code that makes the following call:

```
id<PLResultSet> results = [sqliteDatabase executeQuery:@"select * where id=?",Id];
```

`sqliteDatabase` is an instance of `PlausibleDatabase` (from GoogleCode, I gather).  The code works, but I don't understand it.  Specifically, how does this section work?

```
@"select * where id=?",Id
```

Is the query being made with `?` being replaced by `Id`?  Or is the `exeuteQuery` function somehow combining the strings?  How does this syntax make sense.

(Yes, I am new to Obj-C)

Thanks,

KF

Comment: This is also done in other programming languages and not specific to Objective-C (of course the function names, etc. are specific).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's specific to the method `executeQuery`, in which `?` is used as a placeholder, and the appropriate positional argument is used as filler for that placeholder (with quoting, etc. added as necessary).

Comment: I would never have figured that out.  Thanks!

Comment: One benefit of parameterized queries is that no quoting has to be done at all: the parameter values can be passed to the database as distinct pieces of data.

Answer (score 1):

This bit:

```
@"select * where id=?"
```

is an [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) (as opposed to a [c-style string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string)) which is being passed into a `executeQuery: :` method on the `sqliteDatabase` object. The second (unnamed) argument to the method is `Id`, presumably a local variable.

Guessing from the name of the method, the sqlite wrapper probably creates a [parameterized query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html). The question mark is the syntax used by sqlite to mark where to insert the parameters.